# Creating a path and inverting it for picture cropping

Tags: path, crop, pictures

I would like to basically insert a picture behind the heart and I would like to have it the form of the inner path of the heart. How can I copy the inner path of the heart and then use it to crop my picture?

Thanks so much for your help guys![image]

Comment: Hi.  What software are you using, and how is this constructed? Are these vectors? Usually one would use a clipping mask for this kind of edit. Have you tried that?

Answer (score 2):

I will assume you are using Inkscape for this, as per your other questions. You should tag your question with Inkscape if this is the case.

1. Place an image in position under the heart, lower to the bottom using the shortcut <kbd>End</kbd> to do that.
2. Draw a rough path with the pen tool around the the heart. It doesn't need to be exact, as long as it is inside the black lines of the heart shape, since the black outline of the heart will cover over the rough edge anyway.
3. Select both the path you just made and the image (hint: hold down <kbd>Shift</kbd> while clicking both objects to make a multiple selection), then do *Object > Clip > Set clip*

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much for this amazing video! So helpful! Keep up the great work! And thanks for the tip concering the tag ;)